# Tainted canvases may not be exported.(crossOrigin: Anonymous)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am writing a angular directive to crop image and for which I am going with html5 canvas.

template:

```
<div class="image-holder">
<img src="{{imagesrc}}" image-cropper>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('todoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.imagesrc = "https://www.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/10-dithering-opt.jpg";
});
app.directive('imageCropper', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var _originalHeight,_originalWidth;
            element.on('load', function() { 
                //actual height and width of image 
                _originalHeight=element[0].height;
                _originalWidth=element[0].width;
                element[0].crossOrigin='Anonymous';
                var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
                attrs.src= attrs.src + (timestamp.toString());
                var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                context.drawImage(element[0], _originalWidth/2, _originalHeight/2, _originalWidth, _originalHeight, 0, 0, element.parent()[0].offsetWidth, element.parent()[0].offsetHeight);
                var newImg=canvas.toDataURL();
                console.log(newImg);
            })
        }
    }
})
```

But I am getting the error :

```
 Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
```

Even though I kept the attribute `crossorigin='Anonymous'`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `The "anonymous" keyword means that there will be no exchange of user credentials via cookies, client-side SSL certificates or HTTP authentication` - how does this relate to `tainted` canvas?

Comment: for an image not to taint a canvas, it must be either same domain, or cross domain where *appropriate CORS headers have been received*

Comment: If I read it correctly (I don't know angular) you are setting the crossOrigin attribute after the image has loaded. It's too late. For the browser to request the media with the CORS header, this attribute must be set before the browser starts to fetch the media. If it's not possible, then you could wrap the code to be executed on load again in the first load handler, and reset the src of your element (`element.crossOrigin=true; element.onload=drawIt; element.src=element.src;`)